# Getting a column value

Tags: linq-to-dataset

```
    private string FindTaxItemLocation(string taxItemDescription)
    {
        if (!templateDS.Tables.Contains(cityStateTaxesTable.TableName))
            throw new Exception("The schema dos not include city state employee/employer taxes table");
        var cityStateTaxes =
            templateDS.Tables[cityStateTaxesTable.TableName].AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Field<string>(Fields.Description.Name) == taxItemDescription);//[x.Field<string>(Fields.SteStateCodeKey.Name)]);

        if (cityStateTaxes != null)
            return cityStateTaxes[Fields.SteStateCodeKey.Name].ToString();

        return null;
    }
```

cityStateTaxes is a DataRow, why/how I cannot get the column value inside FirstOrDefault()?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault()` selects the first item in the collection (optionally that satisfies a predicate) or returns `null` in the case there it is empty (or nothing satisfies the predicate).  It will not do projections for you.  So if you use it, it can be awkward to access a field of the item since you must include default value checks.

My suggestion is to *always* project to your desired field(s) first before using `FirstOrDefault()`, that way you get your field straight without needing to perform the check.

```
var cityStateTaxes = templateDS.Tables[cityStateTaxesTable.TableName]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>(Fields.Description.Name) == taxItemDescription) // filter the rows
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>(Fields.SteStateCodeKey.Name)) // project to your field
    .FirstOrDefault(); // you now have your property (or the default value)

return cityStateTaxes;
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Is there any delay by doing the projection first? In this case I am happy to get the first item matching the condition, FirstOrDefault() is more as a safeguard for the exception. My problem  is that I cannot apply [] after FirstOrDefault and get the column value (or I wasn't able to find the correct syntax). Thanks!

Comment: @EuLupu: There should be no noticeable delay.  Remember, operations such as `Where()` and `Select()` are only executed as it is enumerated and `FirstOrDefault()` will force the enumeration until it finds the first item.  It should have exactly the same behavior (in terms of running time) as if you used `FirstOrDefault()` then accessed the field as you have already done.  Using `Field<T>()` is the strongly typed way to access a column value so the above should work assuming the `SteStateCodeKey` name refers to the correct column.